# Construct 2 converting to HTML

Tags: construct-2

I need your help.I recently discovered contruct 2 and I´m not the best at using it.So my problem is, I exported my game to HTML5 and when I open it it says that for security reason it won´t open only if I upload it, the game as some bugs that I can only be sure it´s something wrong if doing it on a website otherwise the game puts all my layouts one over the other and that´s the only way that I can be sure that nothign is wrong with it.

Thanks for reading!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

To test your game just run it with "play" button (you have to open the first layout and then press "play"). You need a web server to test the exported game

Answer (score 0):

Your game works if you upload your game to internet server and it get URL address to it (for example: http://example.com/index.html). When you go to game URL in your browser you can play your game (I hope so).

If you have Github create new project, upload game (html) file (and it's assets) and then get URL address for that project. Please ensure game file is main site.

I'm tried this myself. And I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry if this is not what you think. I don't understand your question fully.